# Prevent Metadata from copying when using "Send To" feature

Tags: document-library, event-receivers, metadata

I have an event receiver to handle items being added to a document library that sets the item's metadata based on various parameters. When in a Document Library I select an item and use "Send To > Other Location" and the event receiver is run and the new copied item gets the correct new metadata.

However, something appears to happen after this, and the new copied item has the same metadata as the original, which is not what I want. Is there any way to prevent this behavior? There don't appear to be any other events fired (such as "ItemMoved" or "ItemUpdated") by the "Send To" process, so I'm not sure when/where in the code I would be able to stop this behavior.